# convert 10 digit number to hex string

Tags: c#, hex, number-formatting

How do I convert a 10 digit number to a hex string in c#?

**Note**: if the number is less than 10 digits, I want to add padding? example
the number is 1, I want my string to be 0000000001.

Comment: Odd, never formatted your own name?

Comment: hehe yeah similar to my name :D 001.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a [standard format string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx):

```
string paddedHex = myNumber.ToString("x10");
```

See the [`x` format specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx#XFormatString).

Comment: The `x` says you want a hexadecimal format, the 10 says you want to pad it 10 digits. Read the documentation in the links I provided.