# Is converting Integer to five digit Binary in c# possible?

Tags: c#

I found some answers on converting decimal to binary and I made this code and its working fine,

```
int number = 2;
string binary = Convert.ToString(number, 2); // gives 10 as binary
```

But what I want is `00010` as five digit no.

And I am not looking to convert into HEX,

How do I get that?

Comment: How about `String.PadLeft`.

Comment: It might be a duplicate but not of [the current duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4416974/convert-10-digit-number-to-hex-string) selected. I didn't find any standard numeric format string that converts the number to it's binary representation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`PadLeft`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92h5dc07(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
var binary = Convert.ToString(number, 2).PadLeft(5, '0');
```

[See a live demo on rextester.](http://rextester.com/IKN10617)

Answer (score 1):

fast solution :

```
int number = 2;
string binary = Convert.ToString(number, 2); // gives 10 as binary
if (binary.Length < 5) binary = new String('0',5- binary.Length ) + binary;
```

**output** : `00010`